# this.packagename not working in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, share, rate, package-name

I wanted to add rate us button to Android app.So I added below code.but "getPackageName" colored in RED.I deleted "this".Then it's OK.Why is that? 
Is it effect to my code...?

```
 Button ratebutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ratebutton);
        ratebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse
                        ("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + this.getPackageName())));
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `getPackageName()` is not a method of the anonymous class created from `View.OnClickListener`, but a method of the outer class.

In an anonymous class, `this` refers to the anonymous class.

To explicitly refer to the outer class, you need to write `OuterClass.this.getPackageName()`, where `OuterClass` is the actual name of the outer class.

Comment: Thank you very much